# Collating repeated text on a single page

Tags: vba, excel

I am using an Excel workbook for military planning.  The planning process takes me through a number of questions on various tabs; the analysis of the answers to these questions leads to tasks, considerations, constraints, requests for further information and so on.  These fall-outs from the analysis are prefixed with abbreviations (T: for task; R: for risk, etc).  I am trying to find a way of collating all the occurrences of the fall-outs and collate them in a separate tab within the same workbook to save trawling back through each tab to copy and paste them.  Is there any way of setting up a macro that searches for cell contents with the prefix and copying the entire cell data from one tab to another?

The prefixes are as follows:

```
A: 
R:
C:
E:
T:
PG: 
FQ:
CL:
RFI:
D/W: 
CCIR:
EEFI:
PIR:
NIR:
RFC:
```

Can anyone help me?  I have no idea when it comes to writing scripts.

Comment: See my profile for an email address if you wish to send me something.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to "Is there any way of setting up a macro ... ?" is almost certainly "Yes" but with such a vague question it is impossible to tell.

This site is here so programmers can help each other develop.  I have seen beginners grow into useful answerers and even the most gifted regular asks the occasional question.  But this is not a free coding site; you must make an effort to solve your own problem before coming here.

You cannot expect to understand code snippets you find here if you know nothing of VBA.  Learning the basics of VBA will quickly repay itself.  Search for “Excel VBA tutorial”.  There are many to choose from so try a few and then finish one that matches your learning style.  I prefer books.  I visited my local library, borrowed a few Excel VBA Primers and then bought the one I preferred.  Twelve years later, I still refer to it occasionally.

Your question implies that these prefixed strings are scattered across a master sheet.  You want to locate all strings starting “XYZ:” and copy them to worksheet XYZ.

I am sure any tutorial or book will teach you how to use `Find`.  They will also show you how to move data from one sheet to another.  What they might not do is show you how to search for “A:” then “R:” then “C:” and so on for the minimum of effort.  I will give you a start by showing how I would work through a set of workbooks.

The macro below checks for the existence of each of the worksheets and creates them if they do not already exist.  I doubt you will understand much of the code until you have mastered the basics of VBA.  What I want you to notice is that quite a small piece of code can selectively create 19 worksheets.

The macro you want will have a similar structure but the statements `Err.Clear` to `End If` will be replaced by a block which is something like:

- Search Master sheet for first occurrence, if any, of current prefix
- If an occurrence is found, loop copying every occurrence to next free row in column A of relevant worksheet.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateWorksheets()

  Dim ErrNum As Long
  Dim InxP As Long
  Dim PrefixCrnt As Variant
  Dim Prefixes() As Variant
  Dim Wsht As Worksheet
  Dim WshtName As String

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Prefixes = Array("A", "R", "C", "E", "T", "PG", "FQ", "CL", "RFI", _
                   "D/W", "CCIR", "EEFI", "PIR", "NIR", "RFC")

  ' For each prefix in Prefices, create a worksheet with
  ' this name if it does not already exist.

  For InxP = LBound(Prefixes) To UBound(Prefixes)

    PrefixCrnt = Prefixes(InxP)
    ' Remove characters that cannot be present in a worksheet name
    WshtName = Replace(PrefixCrnt, "/", "-")

    Err.Clear                   ' Clear record of any past error
    On Error Resume Next        ' Switch off normal error handling
    Set Wsht = Worksheets(WshtName)
    ErrNum = Err.Number         ' Save error number
    On Error GoTo 0             ' Restore normal error handling
    If ErrNum <> 0 Then
      ' Worksheets(wshtname) does not exist
      ' Create new worksheet and place after all existing worksheets
      Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
      ' New worksheet is now active workbook
      ActiveSheet.Name = WshtName   ' Rename new worksheet
    End If

  Next InxP

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

OK Ben, notwithstanding the advice given by @Tony Dallimore I actually think this is quite a challenge for someone with no VBA experience, I also have a slightly different interpretation of the requirement, hence this proposed Answer.  I'll give you some base code from which to learn a little and hopefully for you to modify as hinted below.

For this example I have assumed that there is a blank sheet called "Summary" (with the headings shown) already added to your workbook.  You could use Tony's answer as a basis for you to automatically provide this if it doesn't already exist, or blank it if it does.

[image]

The code below will then populate this sheet with the Sheet Title of the fallout (col A), the row/col location of the fallout (col B) and the cell contents of the fallout as requested (col C).  You could perhaps amend the code to split the prefix into a separate coll?  I am using Q1, Q2, Q3 as the sheet names and data which combines the prefix with the sheet name to constitute the fallout text eg. "CCIR:Q3".

As remarked by Tony, in the absence of data/layout, this is an example of the simple data I used on sheet Q1:

[image]

My code uses two `Range` methods called `.Find` and `.FindNext`.  To find values (your prefixes) they need to be uniquely identifiable.  In your prefix list, searching for "R:" will also find "CCIR:", "PIR:" and "NIR:"; similarly searching for "C:" will also find "RFC:".  This is troublesome so I have modified your prefixes to be "RR:" and "CC:" respectively.  You will need to decide whether either to change you prefixes to reflect this or use some other basis to locate your prefixes.

`Find` and `FindNext` require some understanding so perhaps have a look at [Siddarth Rout's excellent summary here.](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

You may also care to research `Worksheet.UsedRange` starting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Copy and paste the following code samples into a normal code module and run ReportPrefixes - you may have to learn how to do this. There is a 'main' Sub called `Sub ReportPrefixes()` and a called Sub called `Sub addFallout()`.  They can be pasted together in the same code module.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReportPrefixes()
Dim wsSum As Worksheet, sht As Worksheet
Dim prefx() As Variant
Dim fndPrefx As Range, fndStAdd As Range
Dim curPrefx As Long

prefx = Array("A:", "RR:", "CC:", "E:", "T:", "PG:", "FQ:", "CL:", "RFI:", _
                   "D/W:", "CCIR:", "EEFI:", "PIR:", "NIR:", "RFC:")

    For Each sht In Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> "Summary" Then
            With sht.UsedRange
                For curPrefx = LBound(prefx) To UBound(prefx)
                    Set fndPrefx = .Find(what:=prefx(curPrefx), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                 searchDirection:=xlNext, searchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False)
                        If Not fndPrefx Is Nothing Then
                            Set fndStAdd = fndPrefx
                            Call addFallout(sht.Name, fndPrefx.Row, fndPrefx.Column, fndPrefx.Value)
                                Do
                                    Set fndPrefx = .FindNext(After:=fndPrefx)
                                        If Not fndPrefx Is Nothing Then
                                            If fndPrefx.Address = fndStAdd.Address Then Exit Do
                                            Call addFallout(sht.Name, fndPrefx.Row, fndPrefx.Column, fndPrefx.Value)
                                        End If
                                Loop
                        End If
                Next curPrefx
            End With
        End If
    Next sht

End Sub

Sub addFallout(ByVal wsht As String, ByVal rw As Long, ByVal col As Long, ByVal val As String)
Dim nxtRow As Long, wrCol As Long
wrCol = 1

    With Sheets("Summary")
        nxtRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, wrCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(nxtRow, wrCol).Value = wsht
        .Cells(nxtRow, wrCol).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Row:" & rw & " Col:" & col
        .Cells(nxtRow, wrCol).Offset(0, 2).Value = val
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I too failed to see the value of a fall-out without the original context. I decided to ignore the problem since it is easy to pick up values from the left-most columns of the same row or the top rows of the same column. At first, I did not understand you loop per prefix per sheet other than "Summary". What you noticed and I didn't is that there are "a number of questions on various tabs".  You read the requirement as one summary sheet while I read it as one per prefix.  We will have to wait for Ben K to clarify his requirement before we know who is correct.

Comment: Tony, Barry, first of all thank you for helping me.  You are actually both right!  Creating the sheets as Tony has done works well; and the data capture Barry has created also is right.  What I need to do now is try and separate the various values between the sheets so that you only have one variety per sheet.  If it would help I would be happy to email you the document I am using so you could see what I was getting at?  I'd rather not post it for general consumption.  I'm also going to have a play with it now and come back to you.  Thanks again for your help and advice!

Comment: Glad you are making progress.  I am happy to help you further if you so wish.